# Recursively decompressing a String

Tags: java, eclipse, recursion

I have this assignment that needs me to decompress a previously compressed string.
Examples of this would be

```
i4a --> iaaaa
q3w2ai2b --> qwwwaaibb
3a --> aaa
```

Here's what I've written so far:

```
    public static String decompress(String compressedText)
{
    char c;
    char let;
    int num;
    String done = "";
    String toBeDone = "";
    String toBeDone2 = "";

    if(compressedText.length() <= 1)
    {
        return compressedText;
    }
    if (Character.isLetter(compressedText.charAt(0)))
    {
        done = compressedText.substring(0,1);
        toBeDone = compressedText.substring(1);

        return done + decompress(toBeDone);
    }
    else
    {
        c = compressedText.charAt(0);
        num = Character.getNumericValue(c);
        let = compressedText.charAt(1);
        if (num > 0)
        {
            num--;
            toBeDone = num + Character.toString(let); 
            toBeDone2 = compressedText.substring(2);
            return Character.toString(let) + decompress(toBeDone) + decompress(toBeDone2);
        }
        else
        {
            toBeDone2 = compressedText.substring(2);
            return Character.toString(let) + decompress(toBeDone2);
        }
    }
}
```

My return values are absolutely horrendous.

```
"ab" yields "babb" somehow.
"a" or any 1 letter string string yields the right result
"2a" yields "aaaaaaaaaaa"
"2a3b" gives me "aaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbaaabbbbaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb"
```

The only place I can see a mistake in would probably be the last else section, since I wasn't entirely sure on what to do once the number reaches 0 and I have to stop using recursion on the letter after it. Other than that, I can't really see a problem that gives such horrifying outputs.

Comment: Why are you doing this with recursion?

Comment: This is good time to learn how to debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reckon something like this would work:

```
public static String decompress(String compressedText) {
    if (compressedText.length() <= 1) {
        return compressedText;
    }

    char c = compressedText.charAt(0);

    if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
        return String.join("", Collections.nCopies(Character.digit(c, 10), compressedText.substring(1, 2))) + decompress(compressedText.substring(2));
    }

    return compressedText.charAt(0) + decompress(compressedText.substring(1));
}
```

As you can see, the base case is when the compressed `String` has a length less than or equal to 1 (as you have it in your program).

Then, we check if the first character is a digit.  If so, we substitute in the correct amount of characters, and continue with the recursive process until we reach the base case.

If the first character is not a digit, then we simply append it and continue.

Keep in mind that this will only work with numbers from 1 to 9; if you require higher values, let me know!

EDIT 1: If the `Collections#nCopies` method is too complex, here is an equivalent method:

```
if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < Character.digit(c, 10); i++) {
        sb.append(compressedText.charAt(1));
    }

    return sb.toString() + decompress(compressedText.substring(2));
}
```

EDIT 2: Here is a method that uses a recursive helper-method to repeat a `String`:

```
public static String decompress(String compressedText) {
    if (compressedText.length() <= 1) {
        return compressedText;
    }

    char c = compressedText.charAt(0);

    if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
        return repeatCharacter(compressedText.charAt(1), Character.digit(c, 10)) + decompress(compressedText.substring(2));
    }

    return compressedText.charAt(0) + decompress(compressedText.substring(1));
}

public static String repeatCharacter(char character, int counter) {
    if (counter == 1) {
        return Character.toString(character);
    }

    return character + repeatCharacter(character, counter - 1);
}
```

Comment: Collections is a bit too complex, and it would be very easy to implement a for loop to put in the required amount of letters. However, for loops are forbidden, which is why I tried implementing a recursive method to return the required number of letters. but thank you for the suggestions!

Comment: Would you like me to provide a solution that doesn't have a for-loop?

Comment: That'd be great. I'm trying now to edit it in a way but I can't seem to tweak it right. I once again tried adding in recursion (in my pervious code it's the part where it says (if num > 0)

Comment: Hopefully a recursive helper-method to repeat a `String` will suffice, I've posted it though!

Comment: Thanks for all the help, I actually didn't think to make a new method all-together to keep the code clean. I also slightly tweaked it because if the first character in a string is 0, this code doesn't run, but other than that it works like a charm.

Comment: Awesome :) and yeah if there are any use cases that you would like to me implement (a zero, multiple digits, etc.), I'll do it!